# ReactJS - watch access token expiration

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I have an access token (Spotify's) which must be valid at all times. When this access token expires, the app must hit a refresh token endpoint, and fetch another access token, every 60 minutes.

> Authorize functions

For security reasons, these 2 calls, to `/get_token` and `/refresh_token` are dealt with python, server-side, and states are currently being handled at my Parent `App.jsx`, like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isAuthenticated: false,
      isAuthorizedWithSpotify: false,
      spotifyToken: '',
      isTokenExpired:false,
      isTokenRefreshed:false,
      renewing: false,
      id: '',
    };

 componentDidMount() {
    this.userId(); //<--- this.getSpotifyToken() is called here, inside then(), after async call;
  };

 getSpotifyToken(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get_token/${this.state.id}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`,
      }
    };
    // needed for sending cookies 
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({
        spotifyToken: res.data.access_token,
        isTokenExpired: res.data.token_expired // <--- jwt returns expiration from server
      })
      // if token has expired, refresh it
      if (this.state.isTokenExpired === true){
        console.log('Access token was refreshed')
        this.refreshSpotifyToken();
    }
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });

  };

  refreshSpotifyToken(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/refresh_token/${this.state.id}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`,
      }
    };
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({
        spotifyToken: res.data.access_token,
        isTokenRefreshed: res.data.token_refreshed,
        isTokenExpired: false,
        isAuthorizedWithSpotify: true
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
```

Then, I pass `this.props.spotifyToken` to all my Child components, where requests are made with the access token, and it all works fine.

---

> Watcher Function

The problem is that, *when the app stays idle on a given page for more than 60 minutes* and the user makes a request, this will find the access token expired, and its state will not be updated, so the request will be denied.

In order to solve this, I thought about having, at `App.jsx`, a watcher function tracking token expiration time on the background, like so:

```
willTokenExpire = () => {
    const accessToken = this.state.spotifyToken;
    console.log('access_token in willTokenExpire', accessToken)
    const expirationTime = 3600
    const token = { accessToken, expirationTime } // { accessToken, expirationTime }
    const threshold = 300 // 300s = 5 minute threshold for token expiration

    const hasToken = token && token.spotifyToken
    const now = (Date.now() / 1000) + threshold
    console.log('NOW', now)
    if(now > token.expirationTime){this.getSpotifyToken();}
    return !hasToken || (now > token.expirationTime)
  }

  handleCheckToken = () => {
    if (this.willTokenExpire()) {
      this.setState({ renewing: true })
    }
  }
```

and:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.renewing !== nextState.renewing
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.userId();
    this.timeInterval = setInterval(this.handleCheckToken, 20000)
  };
```

---

> Child component

Then, from `render()` in Parent App.jsx, I would pass `handleCheckToken()` as a callback function, as well as `this.props.spotifyToken`, to the child component which might be idle, like so:

```
<Route exact path='/tracks' render={() => (
   <Track
    isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
    isAuthorizedWithSpotify={this.state.isAuthorizedWithSpotify}
    spotifyToken={this.state.spotifyToken}
    handleCheckToken={this.handleCheckToken}
    userId={this.state.id}
   />
)} />
```

and in the Child component, I would have:

```
class Tracks extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        playlist:[],
        youtube_urls:[],
        artists:[],
        titles:[],
        spotifyToken: this.props.spotifyToken
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.handleCheckToken();
    };
  };
```

and a call where the valid, updated spotifyToken is needed, like so:

```
  getTrack(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const options = {
       url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get-tracks/${userId}/${this.props.spotifyToken}`,
       method: 'get',
       headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
       }
   };
   return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
     console.log(res.data.message)
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
    };
```

---

But this is not working.

At regular intervals, new tokens are being fetched with `handleCheckToken`, even if I'm idle at Child. But if I make the request after 60 minutes, in Child, `this.props.spotifyToken` being passed is expired, so props is not being passed down to Child.jsx correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: is`this.getSpotifyToken();` excuted?

Comment: yes, twice. one at `this.userId()` and then at `this.timeInterval`. but not after 60 minutes.

Comment: You're clearing interval id on handleCheckToken, so once this is called, your interval will be canceled and it wont fire again, i think you need to start to interval again.

Comment: well noted. I'm waiting for 60 minutes on the idle page. if it works, I'll let you know and you could answer.

Comment: @CodeManiac now,`handleCheckToken` is being fired repeatedly, like you said it would, but `this.getSpotify()`, gets called every time it does, in `willTokenExpired`, and not only after 3600. so there's something wrong with the conditional or returned values. could you take a look at that too, please?

Comment: @CodeManiac not working. `this.props.spotifyToken` is not being updated in Child.jsx

Comment: Where do you define your `options` object on your child component? Can you give a bit more code around this? If this part of your code runs only on first mount, then this could be your issue as this will use the first `this.props.spotifyToken` passed, and never renew it.

Comment: sure. please refer to my edit.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz or codepen for this i can certainly, take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about exchanging `refreshToken` to `accessToken` mechanism and I think that you over complicated it.

A background, I've a similar setup, login generates an `accessToken` (valid for 10 mins) and a refreshToken as a **cookie** on the refreshToken end point (not necessary).

Then all my components are using a simple api service (which is a wrapper around `Axios`) in order to make ajax requests to the server.
All of my end points are expecting to get a valid `accessToken`, if it expired, they returns 401 with an expiration message.
My `Axios` has a response [interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) which check if the response is with status 401 & the special message, if so, it makes a request to the `refreshToken` endpoint, if the `refreshToken` is valid (expires after 12 hours) it returns an `accessToken`, otherwise returns 403.
The interceptor gets the new `accessToken` and retries (max 3 times) the previous failed request.

The cool think is that in this way, `accessToken` can be saved in **memory** (not localStorage, since it is exposed to XSS attack). I save it on my api service, so, no Component handles anything related to tokens at all.

The other cool think is that it is valid for a **full page reload** as well, because if the user has a valid cookie with a `refreshToken`, the first api will fail with 401, and the entire mechanism will work, otherwise, it will fail.

```js
// ApiService.js

import Axios from 'axios';

class ApiService {
  constructor() {
    this.axios = Axios.create();
    this.axios.interceptors.response.use(null, this.authInterceptor);

    this.get = this.axios.get.bind(this.axios);
    this.post = this.axios.post.bind(this.axios);
  }

  async login(username, password) {
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post('/api/login', {
      username,
      password,
    });
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    return accessToken; // return it to the component that invoked it to store in some state
  }

  async getTrack(userId, spotifyToken) {
    return this.axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get-tracks/${userId}/${spotifyToken}`
    );
  }

  async updateAccessToken() {
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post(`/api/auth/refresh-token`, {});
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
  }

  async authInterceptor(error) {
    error.config.retries = error.config.retries || {
      count: 0,
    };

    if (this.isUnAuthorizedError(error) && this.shouldRetry(error.config)) {
      await this.updateAccessToken(); // refresh the access token
      error.config.retries.count += 1;

      return this.axios.rawRequest(error.config); // if succeed re-fetch the original request with the updated accessToken
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  isUnAuthorizedError(error) {
    return error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401;
  }

  shouldRetry(config) {
    return config.retries.count < 3;
  }

  setAccessToken(accessToken) {
    this.axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`; // assign all requests to use new accessToken
  }
}

export const apiService = new ApiService(); // this is a single instance of the service, each import of this file will get it
```

This mechanism is based on [this article](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/)

Now with this ApiService you can create a single instance and import it in each Component that whats to make an api request.

```
import {apiService} from '../ApiService';

class Tracks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playlist: [],
      youtube_urls: [],
      artists: [],
      titles: [],
      spotifyToken: this.props.spotifyToken,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      const {userId, spotifyToken} = this.props;
      const tracks = await apiService.getTracks(userId, spotifyToken);
      this.setState({tracks});
    } else {
      this.setState({tracks: []});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

#### Edit (answers to comments)

1. Handling of login flow can be done using this service as well, you can extract the accessToken from the login api, set it as a default header and return it to the caller (which may save it in a state for other component logic such as conditional rendering)(updated my snippet).
2. it is just an example of component which needs to use api.
3. there is only one instance of the `ApiService` it is created in the "module" of the file (at the end you can see the `new ApiService`), after that you just importing this exported instance to all the places that need to make an api call.

Comment: looks nice...where is your handling of token you get at login?

Comment: and...where is `const` `SomeComponent` exported to?

Comment: and, for the sake of completeness, I've edited my question so your answer can work with my actual child component,  under a constructor, as to where and how `apiService` instance should be imported into that component, as well as the actual endpoint `/track`, instead of generic `/api/get-my-data`, instead of using 'someComponent' in your answer. I'm still a bit confused as to how the instance should be implemented in my Track component.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this help to understand it better.

Comment: thank you so much. it looks promising; a very robust and stable solution.

Comment: just one last point, if you don't mind me asking. my `Track` component renders a whole lot of stuff, forms etc. how does `render() return null`  will deal with that?

Comment: I didn’t knew what it renders so I’ve returned null :)

Comment: if my answer helped you it would be great if you can accept it.

Comment: I've awarded your answer the bounty. your solution is working like a charm. it takes a lot of refactoring, because there are many endpoints across the app, but it is worth the while. many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

props will not updates on the child, because for a child component they are like immutable options: https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

So you will need some ways to re-render the Child component.

The Child component has already been constructed so will not update and re-render.
So you will need to use "getDerivedStateFromProps()" as a replacement from the deprecated "componentWillReceiveProps" function inside the Child component, so that when receiving updated props from the parent the child will re-render, like this:

```
class Child extends Component {
    state = {
        spotifyToken: null,
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        console.log("updated props", props.spotifyToken);
        if (props.spotifyToken !== state.spotifyToken) {
            return {
               spotifyToken: props.spotifyToken,
            };
        }

        // Return null if the state hasn't changed
        return null;
    }

    getTrack(event) {
        const {userId} = this.props
        const options = {
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get-tracks/${userId}/${this.state.spotifyToken}`,
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
            }
        };
        return axios(options)
        .then((res) => { 
        console.log(res.data.message)
        console.log(options.url) 
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
    }

};
```

Note that in the getTrack function you will use the Child state value and not the props.

Comment: is your code above an example, or the actual code you suggest I use? `someProp`?

Comment: I learned that is it `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`, now. could you please expand your answer on how this would work with my real, working code, props etc?

Comment: yeah, you're right! I've updated the sample with the new lifecycle method.

Comment: your solution fails to compile with the following error:  `Lifecycle method should be static: getDerivedStateFromProps  react/no-typos`

Comment: oh yeah you should add static to getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a rerender of your `Child` component when the state of the parent component changes, you can use the `key` prop.  Use the spotify token as the key.  When the spotify token is re-fetched and updated, it will remount your child component with the new token as well:

```js
<Route exact path='/child' render={() => (
   <Child
    isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
    isAuthorizedWithSpotify={this.state.isAuthorizedWithSpotify}
    spotifyToken={this.state.spotifyToken}
    key={this.state.spotifyToken}
    handleCheckToken={this.handleCheckToken}
    userId={this.state.id}
   />
)} />
```

Though this may reset any internal state that you had in your child component, as it is essentially unmounting and remounting the `Child`.

#### Edit: More details

The `key` prop is a special prop used in React components.  React uses keys to determine whether or not a component is unique, from one component to another, or from one render to another.  They are typically used when mapping an array to a set of components, but can be used in this context as well.  The [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) have an excellent explanation.  Basically when the key prop of a component changes, it tells React that this is now a *new* component, and therefore must be completely rerendered.  So when you fetch a new `spotifyToken`, and assign that new token as the key, React will completely remount the `Child` with the new props.  Hopefully that makes things more clear.

The key prop will not be available from within your `Child` - `this.props.key` inside of your child will not be useful to try to access.  But in your case, you are passing the same value to the `spotifyToken` inside the `Child`, so you'll have the value available there.  Its common to use another prop with the same value as `key` when that value is needed in the child component.

Comment: thank you for your answer. how should this key value be called in Child? could you please expand a little bit on your answer?

Comment: I was going to answer in a comment but it was getting long so I edited my answer.  Hope that helps!  I'm pretty sure there's even another place in the react docs that explains the way I'm recommending the use of `key`, but I had a hard time finding it.  Anyone else know where that's at?

Comment: do you mind elaborating? what happened when you tried this?