# Axios post returns 401 and logs user out, but only on OSX & iOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I have a Vue app using Vue router and I suddenly started getting a 401 on an axios.post `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/`and it only seems to be happening on OS X and iOS.

Thoughts on where to direct my debug hunt?

The error is:

```
{
  "code": "rest_forbidden",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

I post, it immediately fails with a 401, but only on Macs.

localClient config:

```
import axios from "axios";
import environment from "@/environments/environment";
import state from "../store";
import router from "../router";

const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

let instance = {};

if (userData) {
  instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}` }
  });
} else {
  instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL
  });
}

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    state.commit("setNetworkStatus", true);
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    state.commit("setNetworkStatus", false);
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
      console.log(error);
      state.commit("delUserData");
      router.push("/login");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default {
  get(path) {
    return instance.get(instance.defaults.baseURL + path);
  },
  post(path, params) {
    console.log(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
    return instance.post(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  },
  put(path, params) {
    return instance.put(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  },
  delete(path, params) {
    return instance.delete(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  }
};
```

interceptor request success before response 401 failure:

```
interceptor request success= 
{url: "https://panel.site.art/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/site/transfer", method: "post", data: {…}, headers: {…}, baseURL: "https://panel.site.art/wp-json", …}
adapter: ƒ (t)
baseURL: "https://panel.site.art/wp-json"
data: "{"location_id":"rec140ttKVWJCDr8v","items":["recg1W9lQuLLRm8VS"]}"
headers:
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
__proto__: Object
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "https://panel.site.art/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/site/transfer"
validateStatus: ƒ (t)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Where do you store your jwt token? cookies? localstorage?

Comment: @felixmosh localStorage. I'm not great at auth stuff so I'm not sure what's happening. It feels like it's something simple and stupid, but the fact that it's only happening on Macs is  strange.

Comment: @Ronald yes, I need to delete that one, thanks.

Comment: What happens on other machines then? Are you using the exact same JWT on the non-mac machines? My guess is the used token does not give/have the authorization to do what you want to do. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241435/i-receive-coderest-forbidden-messagesorry-you-are-not-allowed-to-do-t

Comment: @Ronald I updated my question with the localClient axios code.

Answer (score 2):

A classic issue with safari & local-storage, there is a privacy config for safari which allows to disable localStorage (yeah, it is not works by the spec!)

Had the same issue in one of the companies I've worked for. Eventually, we wrote a specific flow for this case, with a product tradeoff.

It is better to save it inside a cookie in the matter explained here [ReactJS - watch access token expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347944/reactjs-watch-access-token-expiration#answer-61398092)

Comment: The weird thing is that it was working before. I did make some changes to the flow so maybe that triggered Safari's blocking of localStorage. I've updated my question to include our local client config.

Comment: It is user configuration, it may work on your device

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'on my device'... it works fine on my Windows / PC with Chrome and Firefox, but not on my Mac running the latest OS X, nor on my iPhone 11. Always a 401 on Macs.

Comment: Did you tried your code on osx (mac) with chrome?

Comment: now it's failing on my PC too so I'm lost. The authentication is done through a Wordpress plugin JWT Authentication for REST API and there are also a number of User Role Editor plugins. I think it's related to that. The token is somehow messed up. I added the interceptor response REQUEST success before the response 401.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out by adding a billion console logs to the whole flow. What was happening is the login flow stores the user data (with token) in localStorage and Vuex store upon login. However, the way the local axios client was set up (I didn't build it) the axios instance that is used for the post was getting created WITHOUT a token, even though the token exists in state and localStorage. With a hard page refresh the axios instance is recreated with token.

So, I made the axios get, post, put, delete exports check the localStorage every time.

It's ugly as all get out, but it works. If anyone knows how to refactor this to be smaller, let me know.

```
import axios from "axios";
import environment from "@/environments/environment";
import state from "../store";
import router from "../router";

export default {
  get(path) {
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

    let instance = {};

    if (userData) {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}` }
      });
    } else {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL
      });
    }

    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", true);
        return config;
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", false);
        return response;
      },
      error => {
        if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
          state.commit("delUserData");
          router.push("/login");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    return instance.get(instance.defaults.baseURL + path);
  },
  post(path, params) {
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

    let instance = {};

    if (userData) {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}` }
      });
    } else {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL
      });
    }

    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", true);
        return config;
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", false);
        return response;
      },
      error => {
        if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
          state.commit("delUserData");
          router.push("/login");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    return instance.post(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  },
  put(path, params) {
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

    let instance = {};

    if (userData) {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}` }
      });
    } else {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL
      });
    }

    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", true);
        return config;
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", false);
        return response;
      },
      error => {
        if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
          state.commit("delUserData");
          router.push("/login");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    return instance.put(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  },
  delete(path, params) {
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

    let instance = {};

    if (userData) {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}` }
      });
    } else {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL
      });
    }

    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", true);
        return config;
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        state.commit("setNetworkStatus", false);
        return response;
      },
      error => {
        if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
          state.commit("delUserData");
          router.push("/login");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    return instance.delete(instance.defaults.baseURL + path, params);
  }
};
```

Comment: One copy of your answer is enough, thanks